# Powershell Add-content command how to add string to new line of text file

Tags: powershell

Add-content comamnd how to add string to new line of text file, when i run below command it adds string to the last line but does not add new line
'''Add-Content  "C:\test.txt" -Value "test2"'''

Comment: Try `'test2' | Out-File -FilePath 'C:\test.txt' -Append`

Answer (score 0):

If there is no newline at the end of your current file, like:

```
Set-Content .\Test.txt -Value Line1 -NoNewline
```

(note that the [`Set/Add-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content) cmdlets add a new line by default)

You might add a new line by adding empty line (string) first:

```
Add-Content .\Test.txt -Value '', Line2
```